# Javascript "input" event value is undefined

Tags: javascript, dom, electron

I have an Electron app that needs to monitor an input text field on a form. The HTML looks like this:

```
<input type="text" class="cloneProjectName" id="outputProjectName" value="" >
```

I add an event listener for the element and console log what I think should be the typed data from the input:

```
    projectNameControl.addEventListener("input", function (event) {
    console.log(event.value)
})
```

All I see in the console is "undefined."

I would appreciate any input, I have searched and searched without finding an answer.
Sid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the `value` of the `event` that you want (events don't have a `value`). It's the `value` of the element ***that triggered the event*** that you want and that element can be referenced with `this` or `event.target`.

Also, make sure that your JavaScript `projectNameControl` variable correctly references the `input`.

```js
let projectNameControl = document.getElementById("outputProjectName");
projectNameControl.addEventListener("input", function (event) {
    console.log(this.value, event.target.value);
})
```

```html
<input type="text" class="cloneProjectName" id="outputProjectName" value="" >
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you Scott, that was exactly my problem. I am more than a little confused that in my extensive searching for the answer I never saw any mention of this solution.